# Microsoft Excel Macro: Bulk Reading and Writing First Line and Rest of File

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to make a macro that will bulk perform on all .txt files in a given directory. I would like the first line to be copied into the first cell (A1). And then I would like the rest of the contents to be pasted into B1.

The macro would perform that for all the .txt files in a directory, except it would go to A2, B2...A3,B3 etc

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub Mrig_GettxtData()
    Dim strFile As String, strPath As String, MyData As String, tempStr As String
    Dim filePath As Variant
    Dim strData() As String
    Dim lineNo As Long
    Dim myCell As Range

    strPath = "C:\test_folder\test"    '--> write your path here (without "\")
    filePath = strPath & "\"
    Set myCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")  '-->change Sheet1 as required

    strFile = Dir(filePath & "*.txt")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Open filePath & strFile For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

        lineNo = 0
        tempStr = ""
        For Each a In strData
            lineNo = lineNo + 1
            If lineNo = 1 Then 'tempStr = "" Then
                myCell.Value = a
                Set myCell = myCell.Offset(0, 1)
            ElseIf lineNo = 2 Then
                tempStr = a
            Else
                tempStr = tempStr & vbCrLf & a
            End If
        Next
        If lineNo <> 1 Then
            myCell.Value = tempStr
            Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, -1)
        End If
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will iterate through all the ".txt" files in a folder "in this case it is "H:\data\" in alphabetical order. Any blank text files will be skipped. The first two rows will be populated of the first sheet (or tab) of the workbook where the macro is saved.

```
Sub readLine()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String
    Dim strTXTFile As String, strFileSpec As String

    strFileSpec = "*.txt"
    strFilePath = "D:\data\"

    'set starting rng where data will be saved
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    strTXTFile = Dir(strFilePath & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTXTFile <> ""
        ILine = 1
        FileNum = FreeFile()
        Open strFilePath & strTXTFile For Input As #FileNum
        If EOF(FileNum) Then GoTo skipFile
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine 'save the first line of the document into variable DataLine
        Rng.Value = DataLine
        Do Until EOF(FileNum)
            Line Input #FileNum, DataLine 'save the first line of the document into variable DataLine
            Rng.Offset(, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(, 1).Value & DataLine
        Loop
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1)
skipFile:
        Close #FileNum
        strTXTFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work, i created a macro using the exact code you had, but it did not work. Any recommendations?

Comment: after the first line, my text files have spaces and empty lines for paragraphs etc, does that matter?

Comment: as of now it just prints all the first lines of all the files. A1,A2,B1,B2 etc

Comment: I need the Frist line in A1, and the rest of the file contents in A2. And then the next file first line in A2, and the rest of that file contents in B2 etc

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your original requirements. I have amended the macro. Please try again. If I am understanding you correctly you want all the first lines in column A and the entire text file excluding the first line column B. A1 will be the first line of the first file, A2 will be the first line of the second file and so on. B1 will the contents of the first file, B2 will be the contents of the second file and so on.